# How to add a line break in brackets and braces JSON PHP file?

Tags: php, json

I have the following code that generates data in json php:

```
<?php
    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT
                                id_news,
                                url,
                                cover_page,
                                alt_img,
                                mini_title,
                                mini_description,
                                date_post,
                                confg_img,
                                main_cover
                            FROM news ORDER BY id_news DESC LIMIT 5");
        $stmt->execute();
        $member = array();
        $stmt->bind_result(
            $member['id_news_sport'],
            $member['url'],
            $member['cover_page'],
            $member['alt_img'],
            $member['mini_title'],
            $member['mini_description'],
            $member['date_post'],
            $member['confg_img'],
            $member['main_cover']
        );

        header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
        echo '[';
        $count = 0;
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            if( $count ) {
                echo ',';
            }

            echo json_encode($member, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);

            ++$count;
        }

        echo ']';
 ?>
```

Obtaining the following result:

```
[{
    "id_news": 712,
    "url": "es/deportes/futbol/ecuador/ligapro/serie-a/712/marcos-caicedo-recuerda-su-paso-en-los-equipos-del-astillero",
    "cover_page": "https://i.imgur.com/kg7RBqK.jpg",
    "alt_img": "Marcos Caicedo",
    "mini_title": "Marcos Caicedo recuerda su paso en los equipos del astillero",
    "mini_description": "El jugador de Liga de Quito no olvida su paso por Emelec y Barcelona",
    "date_post": "2020-12-18 03:21:57",
    "confg_img": null,
    "main_cover": "relevant_news"
},{
    "id_news": 708,
    "url": "es/deportes/futbol/internacional/fichajes/708/el-fichaje-que-pretendia-ldu-para-la-defensa-podria-caerse",
    "cover_page": "https://i.imgur.com/MmETkch.png",
    "alt_img": "Jugadores de LDU celebrando un gol",
    "mini_title": "EL fichaje que pretend\u00eda LDU para la defensa podr\u00eda caerse",
    "mini_description": "LDU tiene un competidor por el fichaje del central",
    "date_post": "2020-12-16 20:26:51",
    "confg_img": null,
    "main_cover": "relevant_news"
}]
```

But I need to be able to get a line break between the bracket and another line break for each brace, like this:

```
[
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
    "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
  },
  {
    "userId": 10,
    "id": 99,
    "title": "temporibus sit alias delectus eligendi possimus magni",
    "body": "quo deleniti praesentium dicta non quod\naut est molestias\nmolestias et officia quis nihil\nitaque dolorem quia"
  },
  {
    "userId": 10,
    "id": 100,
    "title": "at nam consequatur ea labore ea harum",
    "body": "cupiditate quo est a modi nesciunt soluta\nipsa voluptas error itaque dicta in\nautem qui minus magnam et distinctio eum\naccusamus ratione error aut"
  }
]
```

As this json data output is shown, what changes should I use in my PHP JSON code to obtain the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

If you are likely to be displaying the resulting JSON to users in a web browser, you can simply use: `echo "[<br>";` and `echo "<br>]";` to insert html linebreaks.

**API/REST Script**

If the result is being handled by any other application other than a web browser, use:

- `echo "[ \n";` and `echo "\n ]";` for programs on Linux/Unix Based Systems (Including MacOS 10+)
- `echo "[ \r";` and `echo "\r ]";` for programs on MacOS Versions Lower than 9
- `echo "[ \r\n";` and `echo "\r\n ]";` for programs on Windows Based Systems

The backslash is the universal "escape" character so if you are unsure about which platform you will be running the script on or want the output to be universal regardless of OS, use the windows format of '\r\n' and each OS will work it's own magic

Answer (score 0):

I do not see the reason why you do it, but it could be something like this, adding `\n` (a new line) and `&nbsp;&nbsp;` (two blanks)  behind the brackets and after the comma

```
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo '['."\n&nbsp;&nbsp;";  // <<<< here 
$count = 0;
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    if( $count ) {
        echo ','."\n&nbsp;&nbsp;";  // <<<< and here 
    }

    echo json_encode($member, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);

    ++$count;
}
 echo "\n".']'; // <<<< and here
```

both the `\n` and the `&nbsp;` must be inside double aposthrophe " "

if the space do not work try with `\s`

```
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo '['."\n\s\s";  // <<<< here 
$count = 0;
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    if( $count ) {
        echo ','."\n\s\s";  // <<<< and here 
    }

    echo json_encode($member, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);

    ++$count;
}
 echo "\n".']'; // <<<< and here
```

Comment: the spaces does not work friend, I print the following: `&nbsp;&nbsp;{"id_news": 713, ...`

Comment: then try to add `\s` instead the `&nbsp;`